# Spliting only by [CR][LF] lines in python

Tags: python, text-files

I've got text file with structure like below (this is how file look in Notepad++):

```
Line[LF]
Line[LF]
Line[CR][LF]
Line2[LF]
Line2[LF]
```

I want to split this file only by [CR][LF], output should be:

```
['Line\nLine\Line','Line2\nLine2']
```

The problem is, that using `splitline()` is giving me array with each line separatedly. Using `split('\r\n')` gives not splitted array with only one element.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm reading the file by following code:

```
f = open(path, "r")
file_content = f.read()
```

`rb` mode don't change anything

**Resolved**: `rb` mode fixed problem, just changed it before in wrong place.

Comment: Try `f.read()` in Python Shell, and tell us what do you see.

Comment: Problem is resolved, updated my question.

Comment: Well, I think maybe post an answer is better than edit question.